# How to get the id of the previous and next sibling element in a nested gridview

Tags: jquery, gridview, nested

I have an ASP.NET nested gridview.  When inserting a row there are 2 dropdownlists and a textbox.  The value of the first dropdownlist sets values of the second dropdown.  When I select the value in the second dropdown list, the values are refreshed and include all of the possible values and are not limited as they should be.  In my jquery `change`function, I need to identify the value of the previous dropdownlist.

How do I do this?

This is my current function that will list all values and not limit them by the `option value`.

```
$(document).on("change", "[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]", function () {
 if ($(this).is(":disabled") == false) {
    //This is the first problem...the value is returned as 0 because
    //it is not specifically identifies the previous sibling of the Service name DDL.
     var DeviceSelValue = $("[id*=recdevgvDDListDeviceNameInsert]").val();   
     alert('device value is: ' + DeviceSelValue);
     $(this).children("option").hide();
     $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");

     switch (DeviceSelValue) {
         case "1":
             $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert] option[value*='cell']").show();
             $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
             $("[id*=recdevgvAddressExtInsert]").show();
             break;
         case "2":
             $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert] option[value*='email']").show();
             $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
             $("[id*=recdevgvAddressExtInsert]").hide();
             break;
         case "3":
             $("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert] option[value*='page']").show();
             $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
             $("[id*=recdevgvAddressExtInsert]").show();
             break;
         default:
             break;
     }
 }
});
```

I need to specifically identify the previous sibling `recdevgvDDListDeviceNameInsert` of the element, `recdevgvDDLServiceNameInsert`.

I tried using:
`$(this).prev().attr('id');` to get the id of the element.  But it returns 'undefined'.
What is the correct syntax to get the previous and next elements in a nested gridview?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
As requested, here is the markup.  It is large.

```
<asp:GridView ID="RecipientDeviceGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="grid" ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DeviceID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblDeviceID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Device"  ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="recdevgvDeviceID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceID") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblDeviceName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditDeviceID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceID") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditDeviceName" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceName") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListDeviceName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                    data-placeholder="Choose device…" class="chosen-single">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLDeviceNameEdit" runat="server"  
                        ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListDeviceName" ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation" 
                        ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListDeviceNameInsert" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Predictable"
                    data-placeholder="Choose device..." class="chosen-single">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLDeviceNameInsert" runat="server" InitialValue="0" 
                    ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListDeviceNameInsert" ValidationGroup='<%# "recdevInsertDeviceValidation" + Eval("RecipientID") %>' 
                    ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Service Provider">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblServiceName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditServiceName" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceName") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListServiceName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="RecipientDeviceGridView_SelectedIndexChanged_EditServiceName" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"
                     data-placeholder="Choose service…" class="chosen-single">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLServiceNameEdit" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListServiceName" ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation" 
                        ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert" runat="server" Enabled="false" ClientIDMode="Predictable"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="RecipientDeviceGridView_SelectedIndexChanged_InsertServiceName" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    EnableViewState="true" data-placeholder="Choose service…" class="chosen-single">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLServiceNameInsert" runat="server" InitialValue="0" 
                        ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert" ValidationGroup='<%# "recdevInsertDeviceValidation" + Eval("RecipientID") %>'
                        ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="recdevgvTxtBoxAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditAddressExt" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceExtension") %>' 
                        ClientIDMode="Static">
                </asp:Label>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueAddressEdit" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddress" ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation" 
                        ErrorMessage="Required field." CssClass="message-error">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="recdevCustomValAddressEdit" runat="server" ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddress" CssClass="message-error" 
                    ErrorMessage="*" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateAddressEdit" EnableClientScript="true" 
                    ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation">
                </asp:CustomValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="recdevgvTxtBoxAddressInsert" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Predictable"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="recdevgvAddressExtInsert" runat="server" Visible="false" ClientIDMode="Predictable"></asp:Label>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueAddressInsert" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddressInsert" ValidationGroup='<%# "recdevInsertDeviceValidation" + Eval("RecipientID") %>'
                    ErrorMessage="Required field." CssClass="message-error">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="recdevCustomValAddressInsert" runat="server" ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddressInsert" CssClass="message-error" 
                    ErrorMessage="*" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateAddressInsert" EnableClientScript="true" 
                    ValidationGroup='<%# "recdevInsertDeviceValidation" + Eval("RecipientID") %>'>
                </asp:CustomValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblActive" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListActive" runat="server" class="no-chosen"
                    Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListActiveInsert" runat="server" class="no-chosen">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                                                 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="recdevgvEditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Edit" 
                    Text="Edit" CssClass="gridActionbutton" ValidationGroup="EditDeviceValidation">
                </asp:Button>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="recdevgvDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
                    Text="Delete" CssClass="gridActionbutton"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Device Information?')" >
                </asp:Button>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="recdevgvUpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation" CommandName="Update" 
                    Text="Update" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="recdevgvCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" 
                    Text="Cancel" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="recdevgvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="AddDevice" Text="Add Device" CausesValidation="true" 
                    CssClass="gridActionbutton" ValidationGroup='<%# "recdevInsertDeviceValidation" + Eval("RecipientID") %>'>
                </asp:Button>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**UPDATE**
When I try to identify the previous sibling object using this:

```
$(document).on("change", "[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]", function () {
   if ($(this).is(":disabled") == false) {                  
      var deviceDDL = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('input'); 
      alert('device value is: ' + deviceDDL.text);
      $(this).children("option").hide();
      $(this).trigger("chosen:updated");
...rest of function is the same as above...
```

The alert displays this:

[image]

**UPDATE**
When I get the `html()` of the element `$(this).html()`, I get the values:

```
<option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
    <option value="1,cell">AirTouch</option>
    <option value="2,page">AirTouch Alpha Pager</option>
    <option value="3,cell">Ameritech</option>
    <option value="4,cell">Arch</option>
    <option value="5,cell">AT&amp;T Wireless</option>
    <option value="6,cell">Bell Atlantic Mobile</option>
</select>
```

I need to get the previous sibling that is also a dropdown list.
When I use `$(this).prev().html()`, the alert displays 'undefined'.

It doesn't seem that it should be this difficult.  The function `prev()` should return the previous sibling element but it does not.

**UPDATE**
Using `$(this).parent().prev().html()` returns the dropdown list in which I need the selected value.  When I try using `$(this).parent().prev().val()` it returns 'undefined'.
I also tried: `$(this).parent().prev('option:selected').val()` this also returns undefined.

**UPDATE PROGRESS!!**
I can get the selected value of the device by using this line of code:
`var DeviceSelValue = $(this).parent().prev().find("option:selected").val();`

Now, I need to get the ID of this object to I can replace `[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert]` in the line:
`$("[id*=recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert] option[value*='cell']").show();`

Comment: You will need to give some more information, what does your html markup look like?

Comment: As requested, I added the markup.  It is large but when I try to reduce it.  I usually get more questions about it.

Comment: That is the ASP.NET WebForms server-side markup. Can you post a minimally complete version of the HTML markup that this page generates?

Comment: It is huge.  What do you mean by minimally complete?  What do you need to see?

Comment: First, in your update, "text" is a function in jQuery, so you have to call it if you want to get the value. I think it'd be better to use .html() in your case though. What I mean by minimally complete is just post the table with one or two rows. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The selected value for the previous sibling dropdown list is returning `undefined` when using `html()` or the empty string when using `val()` or `text()`. My code to get the device dropdown is: `var deviceDDL = $(this).prev('td').find('option:selected');`